# I want to be able to produce an expression which show a pupils year group at the time of a referral

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I am struggling to produce a pupils year group at the time of the referral. The referral field is called Fields!From.Value. I also have the pupil's DOB/ or the year group they are now.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you'll need to add a bit more info. What data do you have available (with a few examples) and how would you work this out manually?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should give you a persons age based on the DOB on the Referral (Fields!From.Value) day:

```
=YEAR(Fields!From.Value) - 
 YEAR(Fields!DOB.Value) - 
 IIF(FORMAT(Fields!From.Value, "MMdd") < FORMAT(Fields!DOB.Value, "MMdd"), 1, 0)
```

It subtracts the year of the DOB from the referral date and then subtracts 1 if the day of the year of the birthdate is before the referral date since that birthday hasn't passed.